# High fantasy trilogy, protagonist is able to slow down time

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for the title of a fantasy trilogy, I only remember the cool part now as I read it a few years ago. The world is more or less medieval type (castles, knights and such) and the protagonist and some people have a special ability that lets them virtually slow down time, but its really an increased perception of time for them.

In this world they have some werewolf type monster that something of an ultimate predator and after the hero manages to kill one he gets his arms and legs transplanted from it. His claws can sharpen at will and I recall him stepping aboard a ship and he adapts immediately to the moving of the ship (balance). And later on he also gets his heart transplanted from some big wolf (I remember it being a she, but I'm not so sure) who he had to fight but he looses the fight, and he learns only later on that he still got the heart. That is pretty much that I still remember of the story.

Comment: I flick the safety off my Smith-Hitachi Godzilla Blaster™ and slow down time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like '*The Hungering Saga*' by Heath Pfaff - in it, the main character gets his arms and legs replaced with those of a beast-man creature called a 'Shao Geok', in order to increase his fighting prowess - this is achieved through a kind of primitive magical surgery. Book one is '*The Noble Fool*'.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i was searching for.